# How to return data from Flutter dialog?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having a dialog which opens up when click of a button and having a Listtile which Radio as a child in order to make a selection. As the user makes the selection and accepts it, I'm trying to update the selected part in the UI but i'm getting a null response while the value is being returned.

This is my custom statefull dialog

```
class _CustomScannerSelectDialogState extends State<CustomScannerSelectDialog> {
  int selectedRadio;

  setSelectedRadio(int val) {
    setState(() {
      selectedRadio = val;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
        child: Dialog(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
      ),
      elevation: 0,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 40, right: 20, bottom: 20),
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(color: Colors.black, offset: Offset(0, 10), blurRadius: 10),
                  ]),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Select the Scanner type',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 15,
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    title: const Text('QR & Barcode scanner'),
                    leading: Radio(
                      activeColor: Color(0xFFCC0000),
                      value: 1,
                      groupValue: selectedRadio,
                      onChanged: (val) {
                        print("Radio $val");
                        setSelectedRadio(val);
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    title: const Text('Barras Scanner'),
                    leading: Radio(
                      activeColor: Color(0xFFCC0000),
                      value: 2,
                      groupValue: selectedRadio,
                      onChanged: (val) {
                        print("Radio $val");
                        setSelectedRadio(val);
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: [
                      CustomButton(
                        buttonText: 'CANCEL',
                        buttonFunction: () {
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                          return;
                        },
                      ),
                      RaisedButton(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10), side: BorderSide(color: Colors.blueGrey)),
                        textColor: Color(0xFFCD853F),
                        color: Colors.white,
                        onPressed: () {
                          print("Selected radio is " + selectedRadio.toString());
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                          return selectedRadio.toString();
                        },
                        child: new Text(
                          'ACCEPT',
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
           
          ],
        ),
    ));
  }
}
```

And on click of a button I'm calling a function as **_showScannerSelectionDialog**

```
  _showScannerSelectionDialog() {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return CustomScannerSelectDialog();
      },
    ).then((value) => print("Value is "+value.toString()));
  }
```

Here the value I'm getting printed is **null** but i need the value of the **selectedRadio**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you only need to simply use the following when closing the dialog:

```
var result = selectedRadio.toString(); // or any value.

Navigator.pop(context, result);
```